# Como puedo agregar un botón con funcionamiento al momento de presionar otro botón cuando el programa esta en ejecución?

Tags: java, netbeans, eventos, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy creando un programita que al presionar un botón con un nombre de cierta persona se me auto copie en el *Clipboard* y tan solo sea pegarlo manualmente donde yo lo desee.

Pero me gustaría más si hago que el programa sea mas dinámico y se pueda agregar un nuevo botón poniendo como texto en el botón lo que introduzca el usuario y pues que se le asigne unas determinadas acciones, pero no se como, agradecería si me comparten de su grandes conocimiento.

Aquí las acciones que tendría cada botón que sea creado con el programa corriendo:

```
private void andresTorresActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    String myString = "aqui iria su identificacion";
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(myString);
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
}
```

Como esta quedando:

[image: Como esta quedando:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues puedes crear un boton y colocarlo en el lugar que quieres que se vea cuando se active pero antes debes ocultar el boton por defecto con el codigo siguiente:

```
this.nombreBoton.setVisible(false);
```

Luego de ello cuando la persona presione elotro boton puedes hacer algun:

```
this.nombreBoton.setVisible(true);
clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
```

ya depende de si quieres hacerlo directamente con el boton si es asi. entonces dentro de la funcion de boton o el BottonActionPErformed pedes hacer los seteadores con los textos o los datos del usuario.